# Axios returns error 503 but postman returns correct result

Tags: javascript, axios, postman

Very unusual mystery that i cannot solve.
Postman returns correct result, however axios returns error 503 on the same request.
API Server is run using cloudflare if that matters.
Both requests are the same.
I even tried using code option and pasting into node.js using native, unirest and request.

All returning the same 503 error. Postman returns correct result.

Any clues, please ?

```
axios.get('https://live-orders-api.takeaway.com/api/orders', {
    headers: {
        "Authorization" : 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI___rest of the token'
    }
})
.then(res => console.log(res.data))
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response.status);
})
```

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Geixm.png)

Comment: Could you show us the error showing in the server?

Comment: answered below in 2 seperate answers

Comment: I have encountered such a situation before, but for me it was something to do with **CORS**.. Browsers have their own way of handling requests that Postman doesn't .. That's why the request works in postman but not the browser. From your responses I can't really tell the exact issue but from what I've stated it is something to do with how browsers handle requests.. as I mentioned with **CORS**

Comment: unfortunatelly it has something to do with cloudflare DDOS policy

Answer (score 0):

from axios
503

```
{
  date: 'Sat, 26 Feb 2022 10:23:52 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  connection: 'close',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'permissions-policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',       
  expires: 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',
  'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',      
  'set-cookie': [
    '__cf_bm=z5pLmezkfksUsS5awDCfl.eVQ5kqxOFlwFLXMloKoO0-1645871032-0-AbYc+T02PzS7pwT8XWlOptzjuhn63sVRzxZvGyIN08AZMY1vba+ZPO1mRo6/ukbcr1+oGmL6gKNtFB/q4iGpRG+3fRYu+ZpxJjnkVqxKM/EI; path=/; expires=Sat, 26-Feb-22 10:53:52 GMT; domain=.takeaway.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None'
  ],
  server: 'cloudflare',
  'cf-ray': '6e3875e31ed04151-HAM'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html response containing something about DDOS at the very end

DDoS protection by Cloudflare
            
            Ray ID: `6e3881a1fd0f726c`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Just a moment...</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-family:-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, "Helvetica Neue",Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.7em;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
    h1 { text-align: center; font-weight:700; margin: 16px 0; font-size: 32px; color:#000000; line-height: 1.25;}
    p {font-size: 20px; font-weight: 400; margin: 8px 0;}
    p, .attribution, {text-align: center;}
    #spinner {margin: 0 auto 30px auto; display: block;}
    .attribution {margin-top: 32px;}
    @keyframes fader     { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
    @-webkit-keyframes fader { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles { animation: fader 1.6s infinite;}
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .2s;}
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .4s;}
    .bubbles { background-color: #f58220; width:20px; height: 20px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; display:inline-block; }
    a { color: #2c7cb0; text-decoration: none; -moz-transition: color 0.15s ease; -o-transition: color 0.15s ease; -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease; transition: color 0.15s ease; }
    a:hover{color: #f4a15d}
    .attribution{font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;}
    .ray_id{display: block; margin-top: 8px;}
    #cf-wrapper #challenge-form { padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px; }
    #cf-hcaptcha-container { text-align:center;}
    #cf-hcaptcha-container iframe { display: inline-block;}
  </style>

      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){

      window._cf_chl_opt={
        cvId: "2",
        cType: "non-interactive",
        cNounce: "95863",
        cRay: "6e3881a1fd0f726c",
        cHash: "0f1d8adbda70f6c",
        cPMDTk: "XmSd0IJe5EHc8Gcr1vr0HeIovzPBb3wFu2XcurMbsvY-1645871513-0-gaNycGzNDb0",
        cUPMDTk: "\/api\/orders?__cf_chl_tk=XmSd0IJe5EHc8Gcr1vr0HeIovzPBb3wFu2XcurMbsvY-1645871513-0-gaNycGzNDb0",
        cFPWv: "g",
        cTTimeMs: "1000",
        cRq: {
          ru: "aHR0cHM6Ly9saXZlLW9yZGVycy1hcGkudGFrZWF3YXkuY29tL2FwaS9vcmRlcnM=",
          ra: "YXhpb3MvMC4yNi4w",
          rm: "R0VU",
          d: "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",
          t: "MTY0NTg3MTUxMy45NTAwMDA=",
          m: "+VjM45BgU2CwU/CzWZy3ROsKsV1bhLRuBt2Q0FIrIdI=",
          i1: "E4ZXXKHeP8b0xoH1sl+iow==",
          i2: "6YyihgI0iq+XJWDYXXaMBg==",
          zh: "x2aJMAZK4y9iaqnHGNXTG/oI/2QXLlT7+eUvTqSVgOc=",
          uh: "ktSFqSgHV+YFXE+rWkkM3nYOCL0H4tAb5WPQZaAHklM=",
          hh: "GKj+ykrLyc+i/BsyUz8F43vrn+tDhrIXHXn66oPtJYM=",
        }
      }
      window._cf_chl_enter = function(){window._cf_chl_opt.p=1};

    })();
    //]]>
  </script>


</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="20">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
          <div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
  <noscript>
    <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1> 
  </noscript>
  <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">

    <div id="cf-bubbles">
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
    </div>
    <h1><span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> live-orders-api.takeaway.com.</h1>

    <div id="no-cookie-warning" class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="display:none">  
      <p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">Please enable Cookies and reload the page.</p>
    </div>
    <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
    <p data-translate="allow_5_secs" id="cf-spinner-allow-5-secs" >Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>    
    <p data-translate="redirecting" id="cf-spinner-redirecting" style="display:none">Redirecting&hellip;</p>   
  </div>

  <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/api/orders?__cf_chl_f_tk=XmSd0IJe5EHc8Gcr1vr0HeIovzPBb3wFu2XcurMbsvY-1645871513-0-gaNycGzNDb0" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="md" value="Ee.2PGe5h4eNh5pWDsULi4X70eX9yUSeytj2FwVkPOc-1645871513-0-AS801SB4jH6F_CoKXgB6JjQbBa5BmKAKt3gZ-PSbQhx62Z7NJk9xV2tOyMzkxDS-1W2LvdjWXKH4pDLtQfizPy_jFfoJozdZoU5YZ9s8yFIC7bf0mhU7PBfV-ixVhOCU9ouArCMFmmj9T9vCVra46aHao3H7TmNSEIUDrlOIHFHaamUplEujzh-gt2re4PHmRiJF0cpENoWYoaz63XbaLAY53wAVxRomuFJ02pavgHwP_n4mw17A_rj2vfoDkuD0_1Rls6qV0P844eCritZcu7eLNQlMPpXxrYYOFuUMVmvQ_bmufNSnSNsm8waUqv2QjvzQFvOFIE05ln4MJqkIuxr77ooZs1JfYn9a9N1KJb8E7t8OfVeARrINzy6D0sDtFyWzchG-QmpeaWWwnK0XH1pLzdnNdNac1D48kv24c_bLtkdje0alm2PpONetpMJqcqLE4jUdkUcJGR0vlsaGRlBArfyxfuQ-vkAqnwLx4smPNOLptgz3XhMBb8HZ76dT1SRhfJ9Sb279mlG4VUhQoK7p79n_PADBieVrSqjeP2vL-KZnZN7drxOV2gLNsbDeFEJpZcE4ap1hFqGSkVUPltVQWawes3cuYFSD0hiDsW8c6MUBltCv7Tzg86OjuXA3vhQcbipSxEV1QRE2kaoAgsWyJOL2UeD3iPMgOV69ACBO" />
    <input type="hidden" name="r" value="IHI_QRJfrURiEf.u75WeIzM0yxwj2ha1_ecaEUpdQlU-1645871513-0-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"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="d22b6174a29235276e41b85b2ae24434" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/>
    <!-- <input type="hidden" value="" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/> -->
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1645871514.95-byOeHqPxzX"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
  </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      (function(){
          var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');
          a.style.display = 'block';
          var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
          var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
          trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/js/transparent.gif?ray=6e3881a1fd0f726c");   
          trkjs.id = "trk_jschal_js";
          trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
          document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
          var cpo=document.createElement('script');
          cpo.type='text/javascript';
          cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=6e3881a1fd0f726c";

          window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
          window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
          if (window._cf_chl_opt.cUPMDTk && window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/api\/orders?__cf_chl_rt_tk=XmSd0IJe5EHc8Gcr1vr0HeIovzPBb3wFu2Xc          }

          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
        }());
      //]]>
    </script>



  <div id="trk_jschal_nojs" style="background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=6e3881a1fd0f726c')"> </div>
</div>

          <div class="attribution">
            DDoS protection by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing/" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>
            <br />
            <span class="ray_id">Ray ID: <code>6e3881a1fd0f726c</code></span>
          </div>      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer...

`const axios = require('axios');`

`const promise = require("bluebird");`

`` var serviceURL=`https://live-orders-api.takeaway.com/api/orders`; ``
`promise.resolve(axios.post(serviceURL)).then((res) => {`

`` console.log(`Status: ${res.status}`); ``
`console.log('Body: ', res.data);`

`}).catch((err) => {`
`console.error(err);`
`return false`
`});`

Comment: please use `axios.get`

Comment: appreciate, but unfortunally no change - still stuck at cloudflare DDOS protection page